# Does LUIS keep previous training after importing a new app?

Tags: neural-network, nlp, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

I have a Luis app “Webapp1”. I do experimental development and testing.

So, imagine the following scenario. I do a lot of development with that app, so it has been through an extensive number of training cycles, let’s say 1000 (is that referred to as “epochs” in Luis as well?).

I export the app by “Export -> export as JSON”. According to Microsoft ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-version) *“The exported file does not contain machine-learned information because the app is retrained after it is imported.”*.

1. If I create a new app with the exported file does that mean, I lose
   all the training and start from cycle 0?
2. If I add a couple of
   utterances and I do “import version” does that mean that I start
   from cycle 0 or 1001?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Well the model, yes, you lose it. But it's not a big issue, as you can rebuild it again if you have the exported JSON file. So for example if a production app is using that model, it will stop working. But if it's not used, you can recreate it any time (model = training data + computation power).
2. If you import another JSON (even if it's a completely different JSON that the previous), it will go alongside existing ones. Just name it different (I usually go with versions - 0.1, 0.2, 1.10...). Make sure each stage is assigned to the correct version (Active - currently editing in the console, Staging - a published version for tests, Production - the actual version in production)

Comment: Thank you for the response and if I may :
1. Why do you say that it's not a big issue if I lose all the training? I am not talking a bout time or computational power.What  I am thinking is that after 1000( number not real) cycles of training the network will have a set of weights that approach the solution of my problem within a certain amount of confidence. If I lose the training the weights will go back the "defult values", would I be a able to train once and have the same level of confidence?Generally I have the same impression as you do, I am just trying to find evidence to support that.

Comment: A model is recreated every time you train it, based on training data, not prior models. And it should be deterministic (same training set should produce same model), thus training data is the only thing that counts. Improving your model does not mean training it over and over again, but adding/modifying the training data and changing the algorithm and parameters (not applicate in our LUIS case, but for ML in general).

Comment: Thank you so much for that.
As far as you are aware is there any documentation to support that? I mean LUIS documetation

Comment: No problem. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-train contains some info, but does not specify exactly what I stated. It is mostly a general concept in ML, not just LUIS. You can test it out, just do 10 changes to a bot and train after each one, then export the training data and create a new one which you will train the first time. They should have the same behavior.